# How to return value to the posting form for fixing error mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

I have a form that post 3 informations.

- Recipe model
- Tags field (string)
- File (input of type file)

On the controller side, I receive the information like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create(Recipe recipe, string taglist, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     { ...
```

In the controller, I validate some information on the uploaded file and on the taglist. If something is wrong, I go back to the Create view like this

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "You must provide at least one tag");
return View(recipe);
```

The problem is that the information that was provided by the user (file to upload or tags) are lost in the process. All the field from recipe are still there since I passed them to the view. I don't want to lose any information.

How should I handle this? What is the best way? I've think about creating a special model that will wrap my Recipe model with the addition of tags string but I don't know how I could handle the case of the file since it's not a string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

*Additional information:* Tags string is not in the recipe model because tags are not a string in the database, they are a list of tags attached to the recipe. Since I'm using a jQuery plugin that needed a string, I'm doing it this way and in the controller I split the tag string and add them to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a view model that includes all the information. In it's simplest form, it might look something like:

```
public class RecipeViewModel()
{
    public RecipeViewModel()
    {
        Recipe = new Recipe();
    }

    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public string TagList { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Then, use this model for your action and view:

```
public ActionResult Create(RecipeViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: ok I didn't know I could use a HttpPostedFileBase type inside a view model... Will try that tonight. thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but after changing my code to this, in my controller RecipeViewModel is always empty. The view is bound to this new ViewModel and everything seems to work but it's empty on the controller side... any idea?

Comment: Ok I found it, my parameter was still called RecipeViewModel recipe and that created confusion for the binder! It work! Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, after validation, it doesn't work. The filename is always lost in the file input. It works for the TagList. Any idea why?

Comment: I've just read that it's a normal security measure by browser... sorry!